# torchtext ImportError in colab

Tags: python, pytorch, google-colaboratory, importerror, torchtext

I am trying to run [this tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/transformer_tutorial.html) in colab.

However, when I try to import a bunch of modules:

```
import io
import torch
from torchtext.utils import download_from_url
from torchtext.data.utils import get_tokenizer
from torchtext.vocab import build_vocab_from_iterator
```

It gives me the errors for `extract_archive` and `build_vocab_from_iterator`:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-a24e72502dbc> in <module>()
      1 import io
      2 import torch
----> 3 from torchtext.utils import download_from_url, extract_archive
      4 from torchtext.data.utils import get_tokenizer
      5 from torchtext.vocab import build_vocab_from_iterator

ImportError: cannot import name 'extract_archive'


ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-02a401fd241b> in <module>()
      3 from torchtext.utils import download_from_url
      4 from torchtext.data.utils import get_tokenizer
----> 5 from torchtext.vocab import build_vocab_from_iterator
      6 
      7 url = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/research.metamind.io/wikitext/wikitext-2-v1.zip'

ImportError: cannot import name 'build_vocab_from_iterator'
```

Please help me with this one.

Comment: What version do you have for `torchtext` (you can do `!pip list | grep torchtext` in a new cell)

Comment: why does torchtext cause so many issues?

Answer (score 8):

You need to upgrade torchtext first

```
!pip install -U torchtext==0.8.0
```

Currently, version 0.8.0 works with torch 1.7.0 (no need to upgrade torch, torchvision)

## Update (sep 2021)

Currently, torchtext is already 0.10.0 and you don't need to upgrade anything.

Comment: Note: The Pytorch doc for install doesn't include torchtext yet!

Comment: does this work with `torch==1.7.1` or only `1.7.0`?

Comment: why does torchtext cause so many issues?

Comment: It doesn't work with torch 1.11.0+cu113

Answer (score 3):

## Update December 2021

```
!pip install -U torchtext==0.10.0
```

`torchtext.data` becomes `torchtext.legacy.data`

use:

```
from torchtext.legacy.data import Field, TabularDataset, BucketIterator, Iterator
```

[credit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66549818/getting-importerror-when-using-torchtext)

Answer (score 0):

This might help solve your problem:

```
conda install -c pytorch torchtext==0.8
```

Comment: does this work with `torch==1.7.1` or only `1.7.0`?

Comment: why does torchtext cause so many issues?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
pip install -U torchtext==0.6.0
```

if 0.8 version is not available

Comment: why does torchtext cause so many issues?

Answer (score 0):

If some one wants to run from terminal a Linux then You should consider what Python you are using.

I checked these answers and no one worked.

Based on the Python version that I have (Python3.10) I used the following installation and it worked.

```
pip install -U torchtext==0.15.2
```