# Getting ImportError when using torchtext

Tags: python, importerror, torch

I'm getting the following error when I try to run this line of code:

```
from torchtext.data import Field, TabularDataset, BucketIterator, Iterator


ImportError: cannot import name 'Field' from 'torchtext.data' (C:\Users\user1\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torchtext\data\__init__.py)
```

I was wondering if anyone knows what the issue might be and how to resolve it?

Comment: Can you tell which version of torchtext you are using?

Comment: My apologies my version of torchtext is 0.9.0

Comment: Could I use from `torchtext.legacy import data` instead of my current import statement?

Comment: You can use the legacy also or maybe it would be good to downgrade to torchtext==0.8.0

Comment: Ok, I'll try legacy first then try to downgrade torchtext and see if my results are any different. Do you want to make your comment the answer?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`torchtext.data` becomes `torchtext.legacy.data`

```py
from torchtext.legacy.data import Field, TabularDataset, BucketIterator, Iterator
```

Comment: install torchtext, `pip install -U torchtext`

Comment: Getting `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torchtext.legacy'`, with torch 1.11.0 and torchtext 0.12.0 (windows).

Comment: Downgrade torchtext to `0.8.0`, On current version i did not see this functionality yet. (hope someone can solve this, thanks)

Answer (score 4):

```
conda install -c pytorch torchtext==0.8
```

This worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 2):

When I installed torchtext 0.8, the following error occurred, so I installed 0.6 and it was resolved.

```
undefined symbol: _znk3c104type14issubtypeofextest10shared_ptris0_epso
```

If there is someone who can't install 0.8, try installing 0.6 with the code below.

```
pip install -U torchtext==0.6
```

Answer (score 1):

I come up with this when using colab, then I update the torchtext version by

```
pip install -U torchtext
```

and it works for me